# Programmatically draw lines between buttons on android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to create a tree graph based on user data. There is no library or anything to help and im just a beginner. I just created 8 image buttons and after the app calculates the data, it needs to draw lines between these nodes to connect them. I have no idea how to use canvas or drawline so any help would be much appreciated. 
  [image]

```
         <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/nodesImages">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/node1"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:id="@+id/node2"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:id="@+id/node5"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="6"
                        android:id="@+id/node6"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/node3"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="4"
                        android:id="@+id/node4"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="7"
                        android:id="@+id/node7"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        android:id="@+id/node8"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/node"/>
            ![enter image description here][1]</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit - DrawView Class**

**How can I use this DrawView class to add the lines?**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    static int startX, startY, endX, endY;

    public DrawView(Context context,int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
        super(context);
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY,paint); 
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
This is not working for some reason:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nodesImages);

DrawView drawView = new DrawView(getApplicationContext(),(int)node1.getX(),(int)node1.getY(),(int)node2.getX(),(int)node2.getY());

myLayout.addView(drawView);
```

**Edit 3**

There are so many libraries for creating complex graphs (line,bar,scatter,etc) . Why can't somebody create a library for tree graphs???? seems easy for those people!!!

Comment: extend an outer LinearLayout and override its draw() method

Comment: can you check the edit please, i have the drawView class, how can i use it to add the lines? just a small example would be very helpful to show for example a line from node 1 to 5

Comment: Extend LinearLayout,  not View

Comment: just tried making DrawView class extend LinearLayout and using edit 2 code, still don't see any line

Comment: as i said override draw() , not onDraw(), you can also override dispatchDraw(), make sure you call super

Comment: ok can you please provide an example in your answer, I made DrawView extend LinearLayout then changed the onDraw to Draw, then how to I use drawLine method because it doesn't accept a canvas parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77749/discussion-between-web-development-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your provide `width` and `height` of your `button` in layout. I use translation to do that. See the below code and the ugly Image for explain @@!

```
LinearLayout nodesImages = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nodesImages);

View v = new View(this); //this, because I write this code in the Activity class
//yah, try to understand values 20, 30,... 
v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(dpToPx(20+20),dpToPx(2)));
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
nodesImages.addView(v);
v.setTranslationY(-dpToPx(30+20+20)-dpToPx(20+30/2));
v.setTranslationX(dpToPx(20+30));
```

with:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Ugly Image for explain:
[image]

**UPDATE** get location of view:

```
    final LinearLayout nodesImages = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nodesImages);

    //using addOnGlobalLayoutListener to make sure layout is happened.
    nodesImages.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Remove the listener before proceeding
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    nodesImages.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    nodesImages.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                Button node1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.node1);
                int[] loc1 = new int[2];
                node1.getLocationInWindow(loc1);//loc1[0] is x and loc1[1] is y
                //for more information about this method, in Android Studio, just right-click -> Go To -> Declaration
                Button node2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.node2);
                int[] loc2 = new int[2];
                node2.getLocationInWindow(loc2);

                View v = new View(getApplication());
                v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(loc2[0]-loc1[0]-node1.getWidth(),dpToPx(2)));//dpToPx(20 + 20), dpToPx(2)));
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                nodesImages.addView(v);
                v.setTranslationY(-dpToPx(30+20+20)-dpToPx(20+30/2));
                v.setTranslationX(dpToPx(20+30));
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: omg this actually works, can you show my that instead of hardcoding the values in dpToPx(20+20),dpToPx(2)), i can get the x and y of the node button ?

Comment: this is the sample data that i might get from the user
0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0
so draw line from 0 to 1, then 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, then 3 to 0 dynamically after reading this array

Comment: Omg. Now is 3:13 Am in my country @.@ so sleepy. Sorry. I can't help now.

Answer (score 1):

Psst... Just do it in XML

```
   <View 
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: i don't know which nodes are connected to which , so thats why i have to do it in java dynamically

Comment: Sorry mate, I kinda jumped without looking there.